# What are elements of $\mathbb{C}(x)[s, t]$ like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I wanted to know what is the "form" of elements in the polynomial ring $R:=\mathbb{C}(x)[s, t]$ in two variables $s, t$ with coefficients in the field $\mathbb{C}(x)=:\mathrm{Quot}(\mathbb{C}[x])=\{f/g \mid f,g \in \mathbb{C}[x], g\neq0\}$?

Suppose I choose some $F=F(t,s) \in R$. Does this mean that $F=p(x)/q(x)$ where $p(x), q(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$?

Edit: I made a mistake in the question. I wanted to write in the second paragraph $F = p(x, s, t)/q(x)$, where $p \in R$ and $q \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.

Comment: If I understand your question, $t\in R$ is not of the form you specify in your second paragraph.

Comment: @Lubin: Thank you. I corrected a typo in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of an element of $R$:
$$
\frac{1}{2x} + \frac{3+4x}{5+(6+i)x+7x^2}s + (8-3i)x^9 t^2 - \frac{10x}{11x^{12}-13i}st + (2i-8)s^{100}t^6.
$$
It is a polynomial in $s$ and $t$, where the coefficients of the polynomial are elements of $\Bbb C(x)$.

In particular, one can always find a common denominator for the coefficients, which means we can indeed write any element of $R$ as $p(x,s,t)/q(x)$ (where $q(x)$ is the common denominator). In the above example we can take $q(x) = 2x\big( 5+(6+i)x+7x^2 \big)(11x^{12}-13i)$.

Think of the parallel with $\Bbb Q[s,t]$, where $\Bbb Q$ is the quotient field of $\Bbb Z$. The definition says that elements of $\Bbb Q[s,t]$ are polynomials in $s$ and $t$ with rational coefficients. However, by finding a common denominator for its coefficients, we can always write such a polynomial as $p(s,t)/q$ where $p$ has integer coefficients and $q\in\Bbb Z$.

(The relevant property shared by the rings $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb C[x]$ is that they are unique factorization domains, which guarantees the existence of least common multiples of the denominators in question.)

Comment: Thank you. I made an edit to my original post. From my understanding of your answer, you're saying that it *is* true that the elements in general can be written as $p(x, s, t)/q(x)$, right?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation. I think there is also a mistake in my edit to the original post also because according to your explanation, it would be best to write $P \in \mathbb{C}[x][s, t]$ and not $P \in R=\mathbb{C}(x)[s, t]$.

Comment: Technically true, although $\Bbb C[x][s,t]$ and $\Bbb C[x,s,t]$ are the same ring.